# SQL Delete statement with nested selects

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, fts3

I am trying to make a subquery in a `DELETE` statement in order to improve performance. The plain `DELETE` statement works but the subquery ones are either deleting all rows indiscriminately, or only one row per invocation. I am confused as to why the statements are not equivalent.

Jump down to "What doesn't work" to see the problem statements.

#### Upfront info

I am using `sqlite3` from `python2` to manage a database of pictures with associated tags.

The schema for the table is:

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "files" USING fts3(fname TEXT, orig_name TEXT, tags TEXT, md5sum TEXT);
```

Tags are organized as a comma separated list so direct string comparison in `sqlite` doesn't (easily) work, so I've add a helper function `TAGMATCH`

```
def tag_match(tags, m):
    i = int(m in [i.strip() for i in tags.split(',')])
    return i
db.create_function('TAGMATCH', 2, tag_match)
```

---

#### What works

This does what I want/expect. It deletes all rows where the column `tags` contains the tag `'DELETE'`. Downside is, as far as I understand, this requires a linear scan of the table. Because of the "dangers" of deleting something from the table I did want to use `MATCH` in case, in some hypothetical situation, a match occurs with another unintended tag ie. `'DO NOT DELETE THIS'`.

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE TAGMATCH(tags, 'DELETE')
```

---

---

#### What doesn't work

To speed things up I tried a trick I read in another stackoverflow post where `MATCH` is used to narrow down the search, then a direct string comparison is done on those results ie

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE words MATCH keyword) WHERE words = keyword
```

---

I tried using this trick here, but instead it deletes every row in the table.

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE TAGMATCH((
        SELECT tags FROM files WHERE tags MATCH 'DELETE'), 'DELETE')
```

---

This is what I first came up with. I realize now it's not a particularly good solution, but since its effect puzzles me I'm including it. This statement only deletes one row containing the tag `'DELETE'`. If invoked again, it deletes another row, and so on until all the rows with `'DELETE'` are removed:

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE rowid = (
        SELECT rowid FROM (
            SELECT rowid, tags FROM files WHERE tags MATCH 'DELETE')
    WHERE TAGMATCH(tags, 'DELETE'))
```

Comment: Please clearly state your question for readers.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the feedback, can you please check my new introduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following query deletes everything because the `WHERE` clause evaluates to a number which if by itself evaluates to `TRUE`:

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE TAGMATCH((
        SELECT tags FROM files WHERE tags MATCH 'DELETE'), 'DELETE')
```

Equivalent to

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE 1  -- or whatever ##
```

Instead, consider using `EXISTS` with subquery that correlates to main query:

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM (SELECT rowid, tags FROM files WHERE tags MATCH 'DELETE') sub 
     WHERE TAGMATCH(sub.tags, 'DELETE') AND sub.rowid = files.rowid)
```

Alternatively, using your attempt, turn `=` into an `IN` as former only uses the first record found.

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE rowid IN
    (SELECT rowid 
     FROM (SELECT rowid, tags FROM files WHERE tags MATCH 'DELETE') sub
     WHERE TAGMATCH(sub.tags, 'DELETE'))
```

Comment: Thank! That makes sense. What does the `sub` marker do on the third line of each block?.

Comment: It is a table alias (can be anything) needed to differentiate between main query and sub query since they both use same underlying table, *files*, really needed for `EXISTS` query.

Comment: Oh! I missed the part where you used `sub.tags` instead of just `tags`. I noticed it works without it in the `IN` query, would it be a performance thing there?

Comment: Probably not. It's alway good practice to alias subqueries as some RDMBS require it. SQLite's engine may internally alias the virtual table if user does not give it.